# Getting java.rmi.UnMarshalException occured while calling lookup() method

Tags: java, rmi

Code which is generating exception is  :

```
SystemManager sm = SystemManager.getInstance(); 
String naming = sm.getProperty("server.name");
System.out.println("naming is :"+naming);
tc = (TransactionController)Naming.lookup(naming);
```

output:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: espresso.server.TransactionControllerImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
at espresso.client.RemoteClientImpl.getConnection(RemoteClientImpl.java: 59)
at espresso.client.RemoteClientImpl.<init>(RemoteClientImpl.java:38)
at espresso.client.MainWinCopy.sendCTRButtonActionPerformed(MainWinCopy.java:75)
at dynamicProject.CustomerImplementation.createCustomer(CustomerImplementation.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
at ...
```

Comment: Duplicate of [java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836994/java-rmi-unmarshalexception-error-unmarshalling-return-nested-exception-isjav).

Comment: @@NikolayMihaylov Your edit mangled the stack trace. You should have used code formatting.